# How to make vim print hint about save the unsaved file before compiling?

Tags: vim

I always forget to save all the files in buffer before compile using the vim build-in compile command `:make`. So is it possible to make vim print a hint about save file just like what it does when we quit before saving files?

Comment: I found that "autowrite" option can solve this problem in some aspect, but i will also autowrite when i type `next`, `previous`, `tag`. I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: Have updated answer with alternative using autocommand. (Of course, you need Vim compile with the +autocmd feature)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit** Re:

> I found that "autowrite" option can solve this problem in some aspect, but i will also autowrite when i type next, previous, tag. I am looking for a better solution

You can use QuickFixCmdPre:

```
:au QuickFixCmdPre * write
```

This example will save files on doing make. See for more info [`:he autocmd`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#autocmd-define).

Of course, this will only work if you use vim's

```
:make
```

If you use other programs, don't use e.g. `:!scons -C src`, but instead use `:se makeprg=scons\ -C\ src` and regular `:make` to trigger all [builtin Quickfix functionality](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#%3amake).

For more flexible auto-writing, see :

---

#### ``autowrite``

I just use

```
:set autoread autowrite
```

in my .vimrc; This is actually quite safe, you'll get warned whenever you risk losing changes either in-buffer or on-disk.

This is also pretty sweet when working on windows, simultaneously having the same file open in another program (say, Visual Studio or Notepad++; both can be configured to autoreload files on change as well).

The best part about this is that it will autosave also on minimize, so whenever you hit <kbd>C-z</kbd> to minimize, the file will be written (assuming it wasn't changed on disk as well), and when you restore the window (or foreground it, in a terminal context) you'll automatically get the most up-to-date file contents.

Comment: I found from setting these, can actually auto read and write data. But i have never seem a warning? So can you explain `you'll get warned whenever you risk losing changes either in-buffer or on-disk` in more detail ? Thank you

Comment: (assuming `:se ar aw`:) **1.** open file in vim, **2.** edit outside vim **3.** edit some in vim **4.** minimize vim, or do `:w` --> "WARNING: The file has been changed since reading it!!! Do you really want to write to it (y/n)?"

Comment: Step 2. is actually quite hard to do. I just tested it by doing `sleep 5; echo bye >> test.txt` in a terminal and switching back to vim _before 5 seconds passed_. Otherwise, Vim will just detect the 'outside edit' and reload.

Comment: `:au QuickFixCmdPre * write` this is what i want. I am very curious that how do you know so much about vim. I am just a newbie of vim and migrate from eclipse recently.

Comment: @user674199: my recipe: spend 10 years with it. Every year, read the full docs (skipping the really over-your-head-boring parts). Everytime you pick up a load of new valuable tools you missed out on. Oh, and http://www.stackoverflow.com is quite nice: just follow all vim questions!

Comment: @user674199: Here are some top commands I wish I had found out about earlier: `}`, `{`, `.` (repeat action) `@:` (repeat commandline) `;`/`,` (repeat fFbB), `gv` (reselect visual range), `''` (last position). Oh and getting used to `hjkl` navigation really improved things (I stuck with arrow keys for the first few years, really).

Answer (score 5):

Just create a simple mapping like:

```
nnoremap <leader>m :wa <BAR> :make<CR>
```

- `:wa` to write all buffers
- `:make` to build
- `|` between the two to execute the commands in sequence.

Comment: You may need to escape the pipe, otherwise it will be separating the `map` command from the `make`.